# Visiting Lake Kawaguchiko, how to get there?

Tags: japan, buses, tokyo, japan-rail, osaka

I plan to visit Lake Kawaguchiko on the 24th of Februari. I'm looking for transportation going from Tokyo to Lake Kawaguchiko, and then from Lake Kawaguchiko going to Osaka. What are my options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From **Tokyo**, you've got two choices:

- [Direct highway bus](http://highway-buses.jp/fuji/) from Shinjuku to Kawaguchiko, about 1:45.
- JR Chuo line express train from Tokyo station or Shinjuku to Ōtsuki, transfer to Fuji Kyuko line to Kawaguchiko (Japan Rail Pass [JRP] not valid), total travel time around 2:30 including transfer times.

To **Osaka**, life gets more complicated:

- There is one (1) [direct overnight service](http://transportation.fujikyu.co.jp/english/gettinghere/04.html) from Lake Kawaguchi to Osaka.  It costs ¥8,500 and takes ~10 hours depending on where in Osaka you get off.
- Fujikyu Bus runs [bus services](https://www.fujiq.jp/en/access/) to JR Shin-Fuji and Mishima stations, from which you can catch the Tokaido Shinkansen bullet train to Osaka.  Both buses take ~2 hours, JRP not valid.
- Alternatively, backtrack to the Chuo line and either return nearly all the way to Tokyo to Yokohama to board the Shinkansen bullet train (both the cheapest & fastest option if you have a JRP), or head north towards Shiojiri and then loop back towards Osaka (scenic but slow and connections infrequent).

I rarely recommend rental cars in Japan, but the [Fuji Five Lakes](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Fuji_Five_Lakes) is one of the few areas on Honshu where it makes sense.  Don't rent from Tokyo, though, but at a suitable station along the way; then if heading towards Osaka, you could drive around Fuji and drop off the car at (eg.) Shin-Fuji stn before continuing by Shinkansen.

Comment: For getting to Osaka, because the bullet train is so much faster than all other available transportation, backtracking to Tokyo and taking the shinkansen is the fastest way.  If you have the JR pass, this is probably your best bet as this will cost you no money except the short 1,140 yen (about $10 USD0) ride from Kawaguchiko to Otsuki that isn't owned by JR.  I would not recommend taking the Shiojiri route - though it is a pretty ride it is quite slow and trains are infrequent.

Comment: Aren't there any (night) busses from Lake Kawaguchiko to Osaka?

Comment: Whoah!  Much to my astonishment, I found one.  Updating answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm interested in the direct overnight service, is it possible to reserve a seat online?

Comment: [j-bus.co.jp](http://j-bus.co.jp) has reservations online, but it's only in Japanese.